# How to define global variable in monaco editor for intellisense?

Tags: typescript, monaco-editor

I have integrated monaco editor, to write simple snippets of code.

I want to make `typescript` variable available globally in this snippets and have working intellisense for it.

I'm loading typescript typings using this code:

```
 const typings = await fetch(path).then(r => r.text());
 monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(typings, path);
```

But obviously without any additional thinks it doesn't work. Because typescript typings created as module, and doesn't expose anything to global.

I can create a global variable with something like this:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(`
  declare const typescript: any;
`, 'global.d.ts');
```

But I cannot assign `typescript` type for this variable. I tried this

```
 monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(typings, './typescript.d.ts');

 monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(`
   import * as ts from './typescript.d.ts';

   declare global {
     const typescript: typeof ts;
   }
 `, 'global.d.ts');
 });
```

But no luck. It doesn't work.

How to expose module as global variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Monaco integration, but when I added the code manually to a TypeScript project, I get an error: "An import path cannot end with a '.d.ts' extension. Consider importing './typescript' instead."  After I make that change, I'm able to use the `typescript` global variable.

However, this approach gives you access only to constants and functions in `typescript`, not types such as `typescript.SourceFile`.  To get that, try the following:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(`
  import * as ts from './typescript';
  export = ts;
  export as namespace typescript;
`, 'global.d.ts');
```

Or alternatively, monkeypatch the TypeScript typings directly:

```
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
  typings + "\nexport as namespace typescript;", path);
```

Answer (score 0):

That work pure js too

```js
///---Webpack.cfg.js---
var fs = require('fs');
var MonacoEditorPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin')

...plugins.push(
          new MonacoEditorPlugin({            
            languages: ['typescript', 'javascript', 'css', 'html', 'json', 'less']
            /// typescript - Require !
          })
        )

let MYDTS = [
    fs.readFileSync('./globals.d.ts'),
    fs.readFileSync('./src/js/RuntimeDeclare.d.ts'),//some modules 
    'declare function myFunc(modulename:String): String;', //inline
   ]
    .join(';\n')
    .replace(/export declare/g, 'declare')
    .replace(/export interface/g, 'interface')
    .replace(/export type/g, 'type');// 'export'is not recognize, so remove
    //import won't work, you need to do it in expanded form

//---In front js---
// validation settings
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setDiagnosticsOptions({
    noSemanticValidation: true,
    noSyntaxValidation: false
});

// compiler options
monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
    target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES6,
    allowNonTsExtensions: true,
    allowJs: true,//!!!Require for js
});

monaco.languages.typescript.javascriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
    MYDTS, 'ts:filename/MYDTS.d.ts');

monaco.editor.create(....
```